# error compiling uClibc (__NR_or1k_atomic undeclared)

Tags: gcc

I am following http://openrisc.net/toolchain-build.html to build gcc toolchain for openrisc or32.
I'm doing 'building by hand' flow and had passed
binutils
stage 1 gcc
install linux headers
and was to do 'compile uClibc' which is composed of commands below.

```
$ git clone git://openrisc.net/jonas/uClibc  
$ cd uClibc  
$ make ARCH=or32 defconfig  
$ make PREFIX=${SYSROOT}  
$ make PREFIX=${SYSROOT} install  <br>
```

when I run 'make ARCH=or32 defconfig', I get this error.

```
CC libpthread/linuxthreads.old/attr.o  
In file included from libpthread/linuxthreads.old/internals.h:30:0,  
             from libpthread/linuxthreads.old/attr.c:26:  
./libpthread/linuxthreads.old/sysdeps/or32/pt-machine.h: In function 'testandset':  
./libpthread/linuxthreads.old/sysdeps/or32/pt-machine.h:41:8: error: '__NR_or1k_atomic' undeclared (first use in this function)  
./libpthread/linuxthreads.old/sysdeps/or32/pt-machine.h:41:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in  
In file included from libpthread/linuxthreads.old/../linuxthreads.old_db/proc_service.h:20:0,  
                 from libpthread/linuxthreads.old/../linuxthreads.old_db/thread_dbP.h:9,  
                 from libpthread/linuxthreads.old/internals.h:32,  
                 from libpthread/linuxthreads.old/attr.c:26:  
./include/sys/procfs.h: At top level:  
./include/sys/procfs.h:32:21: fatal error: asm/elf.h: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.  
make: *** [libpthread/linuxthreads.old/attr.o] Error 1
```

Has anybody had same problem? I use CentOS 6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc searches for the header file from the system in the order

```
/usr/local/include  
libdir/gcc/target/version/include    (libdir was /usr/lib in my case)  
/usr/target/include  
/usr/include
```

my system had sys/syscall.h under /usr/include so that file was used when sys/syscall under uClib/include should have been used. So I added -nostdinc so that gcc doesn't search the standard include path. Now it became
make PREFIX=${SYSROOT} -nostdinc
and it works!
The following command was also modified
make PREFIX=${SYSROOT} -nostdinc install

Cheers!